# Two uses of jquery on website, work one or another

Tags: jquery, web, gallery, slideshow

I've got milkbox gallery and slideshow on one website. First using jquery 1.6, and another uses 1.7. I can make that only one of they working on a time.

Comment: why you are using two jquery? Just remove jquery 1.6 and try.

Comment: didnt work, slider only works on 1.6 and i must have it

Comment: if it is working on 1.6 it will must work on 1.7. 1.7 is the newer version.

Comment: @Friendsofeveryone: New version doesn't mean it will have all features of old one. The properties event.layerX, event.layerY and methods jquery.isNaN(), jquery.event.proxy() are removed in jquery 1.7.

Comment: so what i need to do?

Comment: @kavin yaa i know that's why they have created new version. But i think it will not be a problem for gallery and slideshow..

Answer (score 1):

You can make both jQuery versions work using jQuery's [`noConflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) setup method.

```
<script src="../jquery-1.6.js"></script>
<script>
    var jQuery_1_6 = $.noConflict(true);
</script>

<script src="../jquery-1.7.js"></script>
<script>
    var jQuery_1_7 = $.noConflict(true);
</script>
```

Then you do:

```
jQuery_1_6(selector).slider();
jQuery_1_7(selector).milkbox();
```

Comment: If writing `jQuery_1_6(selector)` repeatedly is too much for you and wish to use the `$` sign again. For brevity you can assign `$` as an alias for each jQuery version, like this: `(function($){/*uses jquery-1.6 $(selector)*/ })(jQuery_1_6);`.

Answer (score 0):

We'll you can give yours `<script>` an ID and then call

```
document.getElementById('script1').disabled=true;
document.getElementById('script2').disabled=false;
```

But you should consider doing something about your loading time.